# How to Fix Google Sheets RTL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, right-to-left

I am trying to use the Kharosthi script in Google Sheets, which is Right-to-Left. In Google Sheets, the script shows up properly while in cell-edit mode, but once it is confirmed it goes back to Left-to-Right.

[Selected](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1osPsW5tR5Z8MhMlXtXri2B1UBtJmEeta) 
[Deselected](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r55KjDqprkneZL5yjuq7awVgrd4m2T93)

Comment: did you try to change locale? that should fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to File > Spreadsheet settings and change locale to RTL language

---

last option would be to use formula or script to reverse the string

```
function REVERSE(string) {
  if (typeof string != 'string') {
    return null;
  }
  return string.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

---

```
=REVERSE(A1)
```

---

or without script:

```
=JOIN(, INDEX(MID(A2, LEN(A2)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))+1, 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was really helpful.

Comment: Working fine without script :)